# Conditionally import conditionally existing file in Vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, dynamic-import

I need to import a file into my project when an environment variable is set, say `dist/built.esm.js`. It's implied that when the environment variable is set, the file will exist, otherwise it may or may not exist. It seems straightforward to just wrap a call to `import` in an if statement that checks for the environment variable, but Vue throws the below warning even if the if statement never passes:

[image: Screenshot of compile error]

And the code:

```js
if (process.env.VUE_APP_USE_COMPILED == 'true') {
    const compiledPackage = require('./dist/built.esm.js')
    Vue.use(compiledPackage)
}
```

Setting the if statement to always be false in a nondeterminate way (setting a string var and then comparing it to a different value, instead of just `if (false)`) results in the same problem, which rules out any possibility of the environment variable being 'true' when it isn't supposed to be.

A temporary workaround I found is to wrap the import in a try/catch, which instead displays a warning instead of an error:

[image: Screenshot of compile warning]

How can I get rid of the errors and warnings completely? I do want it to still error if the file doesn't exist but the environment variable has been set to true, but it shouldn't fail or warn on compilation if the statement hasn't even executed yet.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Good catch. I updated my example code and screenshots to properly import.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```js
if (process.env.VUE_APP_USE_COMPILED == 'true') {
  import('dist/built.esm.js')
    .then(obj => Vue.use(obj))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I think `import()` and `require()` are very similar and their differences aren't related to what's causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

> but it shouldn't fail or warn on compilation if the statement hasn't even executed yet

Compilation happens *before* execution. If you get a compile error, that means something went wrong *before* your code was executed, including any conditionals.

What I believe happens here is that you're using webpack, and it's trying to include `dist/built.esm.js` in your bundle. Behind the scenes, webpack actually replaces `require` with some magic. <s>To get around this, use `__non_webpack_require__` instead</s>

You could try setting up a compile-time constant using [DefinePlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin) in your webpack config, maybe something like

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        // this is resolved compile-time
        USE_COMPILED: process.env.VUE_APP_USE_COMPILED == 'true'
    })
]
```

Then, in your code

```
if (USE_COMPILED) require('./dist/built.esm.js')
```

Here the value of `USE_COMPILED` should be replaced by webpack compile-time with `true` if your environment var is set to `'true'`, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't seem to work in Vue. I'm getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` on runtime now. I believe this is because require is part of NodeJS and isn't available in the browser.

Comment: Oh I didn't see you've found a solution. Updated my answer anyway, and learned a bit from yours as well! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out on my own. I used the `resolve.alias` property in the Webpack configuration to allow a 'soft fail' when the file doesn't exist. I changed my import to use an alias (`my-compiled-package-alias`), which would conditionally resolve to either the built file or an empty dummy file (`dev/import-dummy.js`). I had to use `resolve.alias` rather than `resolve.fallback`, since Vue2 uses Webpack v4 which doesn't include the latter property.

My updated code:

```js
if (process.env.VUE_APP_USE_COMPILED == 'true') {
    const compiledPackage = require('my-compiled-package-alias')
    Vue.use(compiledPackage)
}
```

In my `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "my-compiled-package-alias":
          process.env.VUE_APP_USE_COMPILED ? "./dist/built.esm.js": "./import-dummy.js"
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```